# How can I stream an mp4 file stored in Azure Blob Storage using range headers and partial content from an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to create an Azure function that streams mp4 files from Azure Blob Storage to clients such as the HTML video tag, using request range headers and partial responses (http status code 206s). I am using an Azure function so that I can implement required security checks later.

The FileStreamResult class can handle the range requests from the html video tag automatically, so the following works nicely to stream a video from the local file system to the browser, allowing the user to scan forwards/backwards through the video at will:

```
    [FunctionName("StreamVideo")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        // This stream is seekable!
        Stream str = File.OpenRead($@"C:\temp\BigBuckBunny.mp4");

        return new FileStreamResult(str, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4").MediaType)
        {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true,
        };
    }
```

I want to do exactly this, but using a file that sits in Azure Blob Storage. The following code does not work. It returns the whole file in a single response with http status code 200. Presumably this is because the stream is not seekable?

```
    [FunctionName("StreamVideo")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string containerName = req.Query["container"];
        string blobName = req.Query["blob"];

        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE", new BlobClientOptions(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_12_12));

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

        // This stream is NOT seekable!
        Stream str = await blob.OpenReadAsync();

        return new FileStreamResult(str, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4").MediaType)
        {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true,
        };
    }
```

How can I get this to work? Note that I have implemented a similar solution using Web Api for .NET Framework 4.x which uses PushStreamContent with the same media files so I know the mp4 files in Blob Storage are okay. My function targets .NET Core 3.1 and I'm testing it all locally at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work using the following solution. This results in 206 responses from my Azure Function with payloads as defined by the `chunkSize` variable (in this case 896.2kB).

```
        [FunctionName("StreamVideo")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            string containerName = req.Query["container"];
            string blobName = req.Query["blob"];

            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE",
                new BlobClientOptions(BlobClientOptions.ServiceVersion.V2019_12_12));

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            Response<BlobProperties> blobPropertiesResponse = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
            long blobFileLength = blobPropertiesResponse.Value.ContentLength;

            long chunkSize = 1000000;
            string[] rangeHeaders = req.Headers["Range"][0].Substring(6).Split("-");
            long start = int.Parse(rangeHeaders[0]);
            long end = string.IsNullOrEmpty(rangeHeaders[1])
                ? Math.Min(start + chunkSize, blobFileLength - 1)
                : Math.Min(start + chunkSize, long.Parse(rangeHeaders[1]));

            Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync(start);

            var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(stream), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent,
            };

            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = end - start + 1;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(start, end, blobFileLength);
            httpResponseMessage.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
```

And this is the Firefox network output:

[image: Firefox network output showing range headers etc]

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your code, and seems no error there. And here're something you can check.

1.Nav to azure blob storage, and check if the video's content-type is `video/mp4` or not.

2.For `MediaTypeHeaderValue` namespace, I'm using this one: `using System.Net.Http.Headers;`

3.And here is the packages I'm using:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
```

And in my side, I can see the response code is actually 206. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Comment: It's the Azure Function that needs to return the 206. It works when using a local file but `EnableRangeProcessing` doesn't like the stream returned from Azure (because CanSeek == false).  I *think* you'd need to create a stream wrapper that is seekable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I have files of type video/mp4 and application/octet-stream, but my function always returns the whole file with a 200 response. I've tried using the same package versions as yours, and the namespace I use for MediaTypeHeaderValue is the same. Can I confirm that you are getting 206 responses from your function? My function does get 206 responses from Blob Storage, but I want my function to return 206s to its clients in turn. e.g. `<video><source src="http://localhost:7071/api/StreamVideo?container=x&blob=y.mp4"></video>`